# pandas: Issue with filtering datetime values based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am facing any issue related to filtering out events that were active during a certain time interval i.e. 7 to 9 given the following dataframe:

```
EventId             StartTime                       EndTime            
18   2013-04-11 16:33:11.735342100   2013-04-11 17:16:47.976164100  
19   2013-04-10 16:33:46.575337300   2013-04-11 18:10:08.428443900  
20   2013-04-10 17:17:04.033083300   2013-04-11 18:10:13.907757900  
21   2013-04-11 00:10:24.293352100   2013-04-11 18:45:17.754240800  
23   2013-04-11 01:11:20.278558900   2013-04-11 18:45:00.435247300  
25   2013-04-15 09:42:22.549026700   2013-04-15 23:54:33.389964300  
26   2013-04-16 07:42:24.588807700   2013-04-16 17:42:41.077751300  
28   2013-04-19 16:51:22.699240800   2013-04-19 18:39:03.167468100  
31   2013-04-19 18:30:56.891621300   2013-04-19 19:42:50.418640200  
17   2013-04-20 16:07:07.327879000   2013-04-20 22:17:17.783053600
```

I want to get those events that were active during 7-9am including 8, and used following query, after extracting hours as a separate column.

```
df['StartTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['StartTime'])

df['EndTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['EndTime'])

df['StartHr']=df['StartTime'].dt.hour
df['EndHr']=df['EndTime'].dt.hour
df[((df['StartHr']<=7)| (df['StartHr']==8)) & ((df['EndHr']==8)|(df['EndHr']>=9))]
```

It works as intended, but given the data-set it fails to get some of the results e.g event Id `20`

```
            20   2018-05-10 17:17:04.033083300   2018-05-11 18:10:13.907757900
```

as this event is active in the time interval 7-9 next day, but i am unable to get it. Same goes for `id 26` and `21` Any help regarding solving this issue. How can i compare date-time values in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you could have simpler conditions, i.e :

```
df[((df['StartHr']<=8)) & ((df['EndHr']>=8))]
```

I can't think of something simpler than taking the difference between the end time and the start time and compare it to 79200 s, which corresponds to the number of seconds between an event started at 9 am and ended at 7 am the morning after, i.e the limit duration for your case (22h).

My code looks like this :

```
limit_delta = 79200
test_df['diff'] = (test_df['EndTime'] - test_df['StartTime']).map(lambda td : td.total_seconds())
test_df[(((test_df['StartHr']<=8) & (test_df['EndHr']>=8)) | (test_df['diff'] <= limit_delta))]
```

Please let me know if that solved your problem.

Comment: actually its missing out on event 20, which is active during this range 7-9, and it started on previous day.

Comment: Yep, I should have made an or and not an and. I'm editing my answer. Tested it and now it works

Comment: An alternative attempt.

Comment: I think your solution only replace the test on the hour, are you filtering out the 20 index ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a go.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'EventId':[18,19,20,21], 'startTime':['2013-04-11 07:33:11.735342100','2013-04-10 16:33:46.575337300','2013-04-10 08:17:04.033083300','2013-04-11 00:10:24.293352100'],'EndTime':['2013-04-11 08:16:47.976164100','2013-04-11 18:10:08.428443900','2013-04-11 09:10:13.907757900','2013-04-11 18:45:17.754240800']})
```

Coerce dates into datetime

```
df['startTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['startTime'])
df['EndTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['EndTime'])
df.set_index(['startTime'], inplace=True)
```

Set each of the time epoch, start and end to index and extract suitable time using [.between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html)

```
df['StartHr']=df.index.time
a=df.iloc[:,:1].between_time('07:00:00', '09:00:00')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
a.reset_index(inplace=True)

df.set_index(['EndTime'], inplace=True)
df['EndHr']=df.index.time
b=df.iloc[:,:-2].between_time('07:00:00', '09:00:00')
b.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Merge the two results

```
df2=pd.merge(a, b, on='EventId')
```